# Mounting Data From Drive into Colab (Error)

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory

I tried to mount a file from **Google drive** into **Colab** by using the following lines:

1. `from google.colab import drive`
2. `drive.mount('/content/drive')`

It gives me the following error:

**Error
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google Account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.** as depicted in the screenshot.

I tried to restart Chrome, restart PC, disabled third-party cookies and reset runtime but it did not working yet. [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9jwz.png)

Comment: Does this error persist in an incognito window? The most common cause of the problem is an issue with extensions.

Comment: Yes. I tried using an incognito window but unfortunately I faced the same issue.